# Need to install new distro in LUKS disk

Tags: linux, disk, luks, cryptography

I have a disk encrypted with LUKS and running OpenSuse. I want to to install Fedora in the / partition. The /home is a different partition on the LUKS disk. How can I mount the / so the Fedora installer will use it? The automated Anaconda install does not seem capable of doing this.

I said Fedora, but you can see as a generic question: how to mount an encrypted / partition to install a new distro into it?

Comment: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/76959/is-it-possible-to-do-full-disk-encryption-after-install/ try this

Comment: You will need to to a LOT of things at your command line. Here you have a crude example of what you have to do: http://askubuntu.com/questions/653408/mounting-encrypted-luks-partition-from-live-cd - load `lvm` and `dm-crypt` drivers, use `luks-open` to map the driver and then, scan for lvm devices

Comment: I think that it is just better to make a backup, and use Anaconda to make a fresh Fedora Install with Full Disk Encryption...